# Stack going out of scope. Maybe not calling it correctly?

Tags: c++, vector, scope, polymorphism

The issue I am having is with my vector going out of scope. Both the constructor and the other method are being called in the main one right after another but the problem is that after the constructor runs the vector goes out of scope. Anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this? I thought i fixed it but just made things worse.

header:

```
struct input
{
    bool dirtyBit;
    int statusBit; //0 not in cache, 1 in cache, 2 in 2nd cache
    bool writeStatus; //write = 1 read = 0
    int address;
    int indivBlockIndex;
    int indivBlockOffset;
};

class Cache
{

public:

    vector<input > dataBase;
    Cache(string);
    ~Cache();

    void DirectMapped(int, int);
};
```

implementation:

```
Cache::Cache(string infile)
{
    ifstream in(infile);

    string readWriteStatus;
    int Addr;
    while (in >> readWriteStatus >> hex >> Addr)
    {
        input contents;
        //contents = new input;
        if (readWriteStatus == "read")
            contents.writeStatus = true;
        else if (readWriteStatus == "write")
            contents.writeStatus = false;
        contents.address = Addr;
        contents.dirtyBit = false;
        contents.statusBit = 0;
        contents.indivBlockIndex = -1;
        contents.indivBlockOffset = -1;
        dataBase.push_back(contents);

    }
}

Cache::~Cache(){}

void Cache::DirectMapped(int cacheSize, int blockSize)
{
    //initial stats needed
    int blockCount = cacheSize/blockSize; //number of total blocks
    //clear out the cache
    for (int i = 0; i < dataBase.size(); i++)
        dataBase[i].statusBit = 0;
        //other stuff not related to question
}
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    //string in = argv[1]; 
    string inputfile = "C:/Users/Christopher/Downloads/testprac";
    string infile = inputfile.append(".trace");
    Cache myCache(infile);

    // Parse Command Line Argument
//    if(argc != 2)
//        cout << "ERROR: Improper Number of Arguments" << endl;
//    else
//    {
    int i = 1024, j = 8;
    myCache.DirectMapped(i,j);

        system ( "pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The main makes a call directly from `myCache(infile)` to `myCache.DirectMapped(i,j)` in two consecutive lines.

Thanks for your help guys. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Show `main` - what has gone out of scope and why do you think this?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes out of scope"? `dataBase` is a member object so it should not happen. What do you observe as a result?

Comment: Once you tell us why you think the member variable has gone out of scope, I might then be tempted to ask about the `//other stuff not related to question`

Comment: @splrs i observe that at the end of the constructor, the size of the vector is 3, then before even the first line of the next method runs it says that the vector is a huge number in size.

Comment: What error are you getting? And at present, with the values you pass into `DirectMapped()`, you're calculating an unused value.

Comment: @doctorlove the vector is junk before it even runs into that code unfortunately

Comment: "Before the first line" is one point where debuggers frequently aren't able to display the correct values of anything (because they haven't been set up). It's more likely that the vector isn't *in* scope yet. Step into the function before drawing any conclusions.

Comment: @splrs i know that its an uncalculated variable. I made it that way on here instead of showing the loop it takes to go in it. I am confident that that loop is correct.

Comment: oh my god. @molbdnilo you're correct. god that was dumb of me. an hour wasted... thank you. if you want to formulate your comment as an answer ill give you the check

Comment: So was there even issue with the code at that point? Happy to help weedle out what the problem was btw ;-)

Comment: Try writing tests to verify things, instead of using a debugger - debuggers are for getting rid of bugs. Write tests and don't write bugs ;-)

Comment: @user3084848 I have wasted quite a bit of time on this "problem" too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Before the first line" of a function is one point where debuggers frequently aren't able to display the correct values of anything (because things haven't been set up).

It's actually more likely that the vector isn't *in* scope yet.

Step into the function before drawing any conclusions.